# Functional tests with specific route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, functional-testing

In my config/routes.rb, I have created a specific route targeting the data controller:

```
match '/things/:id/data' => 'data#get', :via => :get
```

When I set up a functional test, I got the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:controller=>"data", :action=>"get"}
```

My test is:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end

class DataControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    sign_in users(:one)
  end

  test "should get last data of thing" do
    get :get
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

How can I specify in the test that /things/:id/data needs to be used to match data#get ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
test "should get last data of thing" do
  get :get, id => "ID OF YOUR THING"
  assert_response :success
end
```

`data`  is a member_action so you need to provide ID of your resource( thing in your case)

Comment: it went one step further with your approach, but I now have the following error: Expected response to be a <:success>, but was <406>

Comment: can you post result of `rake routes | grep "data"`

Comment: btw routing issue is resolved, its your spec which is not getting expected results :)

Comment: The result of the grep is: GET /things/:id/data(.:format)            data#get

Comment: The error 406 was indeed a problem with the fixture not having the correct id. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wondering aloud, if you changed `get` to `show`, does it work? If so, I fear that overwriting method names for the similar verb names is messing things up. Barring that, what does your route test say?